# Domain Controller dropped from domain

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

While in the process of making some changes in my environment I set up a new Domain Controller (2019) and promoted it, did some testing and verified it was working properly.
I demoted my old DC (2016) (I know I should not have done this without first setting up a third DC but I guess I won't make that mistake again)
I began installing the AD connector from JumpCloud (Again I did not look and see that it is not supported on 2019. Another mistake I won't make again)
On reboot, my DC did not come back up and instead had the infinite circle error.
I ended up trying to get it up and running and eventually went through and selected start using last known good configuration.

When I got back in I noticed that the computer name was now changed back to the system default.

I attempted to change the computer name back to what I had set it to that did not work, I removed the DC from the domain and put it into a workgroup. (VERY BAD DECISION)

Now my only DC is not on my domain and won't rejoin the domain.

I have about 6 users and 9 devices that are all relying on this domain to function properly so just starting over or anything like that wont work.

Comment: Do you have backups of the old DC that include the System State?

Comment: Unfortunately no.
I did not erase the 2016 DC so it still exists just as a demoted DC.

Comment: I'm Greg with JumpCloud and work on the product side of the house. My feeds picked this up. Just wanted to extend a hand to help where we can. You're correct, our AD Bridge agent does not yet support WS 2019, but we do have quite a few members on the support staff with windows domain experience and would be happy to try and help you in this situation. Lob us a note at support@jumpcloud.com and we'll pair with you.